# appears some text that is not in the code of this page

Tags: html

I am making a page, and in this

http://paypercall.org/app-install/ie-restart.html

apears that strange text, up and down in the page

<<<<<<< HEAD <<<<<<< HEAD

======= ======= >>>>>>> ddc730db718a7c5f4a510aa375ac8aa91f1e46d3 test no stylesheet & no footer & no header >>>>>>> b2d2e680fa867e39690b459ce45b597e67fe96c9

I dont know why it can be, in the code html these texts doesnt appears

please help

Comment: It's in your HTML, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unexpected text is definitely present in the source code that's being sent to the browser - you can verify this by doing a 'view source' from your browser of choice.

This looks like a diff output, is it possible there was a conflict when you committed to a version control system? If so, it looks like the page has been uploaded before the conflict was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In html source codes of the page, you can find those nonsense codes. Check your html source code and re upload the html page.